# Script error: –le: binary operator expected

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm just starting shell scripting and I got errors trying to execute the follow script:

I have the following script in a `script.sh` file

```
echo “enter a value”
read n
s=0
i=0
while [ $i –le $n ]
do
  if [ `expr $i%2` -eq 0 ]
  then
    s= `expr $s + $i `
  fi
  i= `expr $i + 1`
done
echo “sum of n even numbers”
echo $s
```

Script output:

```
akhil@akhil-Inspiron-5559:~/Desktop/temp$ chmod 755 script.sh
akhil@akhil-Inspiron-5559:~/Desktop/temp$ ./script.sh
“enter a value”
3
./script.sh: line 5: [: –le: binary operator expected
“sum of n even numbers”
0
```

What is the source of the error I got?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source of the error: `[: –le: binary operator expected` is the fact you are using the `unicode` version of `–` instead of the regular `-`

Note: The same apply for the `unicode` `”` you are using instead of regular `"`

I've reformat your code to be as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter a value"
read -r n
s=0
i=0
while [ $i -le "$n" ]
  do
  if [ "$(expr $i%2)" -eq 0 ]
  then
    s=$(expr $s + $i)
  fi
  i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
echo "sum of n even numbers"
echo "$s"
```

I made the following changes:

- Replaced the `unicode` version of chars you used
- Added `#!/bin/bash`
- Deleted `space` after the `=` sign
- Some extra improvements.

Comment: Why do we have two versions? Also, if `–` is the unicode version, which version is the "regular"  `-`

Comment: @Rockstar5645 - I assume that you `copy/paste` the `-le` operation from a `unicode source` (`html` or `word-document`),  hence you got the `unicode` version of the `-` and `"`.

Answer (score 4):

Yaron's answer helps you understand and remove the syntax errors.

My answer uses some 'nicer' syntax to do the same thing and something else, that might be what you want.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter a number: " n

s=0
i=1
j=0
while [ $i -le $n ]
do
  if [ $(( i % 2 )) -eq 0 ]
  then
    s=$(( s + i ))
    j=$(( j + 1 ))
  fi
  i=$(( i + 1 ))

#  uncomment: remove the '#' from the beginning of the line

#  echo "i=$i"  # uncomment to get debug output
done
#echo "n=$n"  # uncomment to get debug output 
#echo "j=$j"  # uncomment to get debug output
#echo "s=$s"  # uncomment to get debug output

echo "Is this what you want?"
echo "sum of $j even numbers ( <= $n ) = $s"
echo "or is this what you want?"

s=0
for ((i=1;i<=n;i++))
do
    echo -n "$(( 2*i )) "
    s=$(( s + 2*i ))
done
echo ""
echo "sum of $n even numbers = $s"
```

Running test examples,

```
$ ./sum-of-even-numbers 
enter a number: 3
Is this what you want?
sum of 1 even numbers ( <= 3 ) = 2
or is this what you want?
2 4 6 
sum of 3 even numbers = 12

$ ./sum-of-even-numbers
enter a number: 4
Is this what you want?
sum of 2 even numbers ( <= 4 ) = 6
or is this what you want?
2 4 6 8 
sum of 4 even numbers = 20

$ ./sum-of-even-numbers
enter a number: 6
Is this what you want?
sum of 3 even numbers ( <= 6 ) = 12
or is this what you want?
2 4 6 8 10 12 
sum of 6 even numbers = 42
```